# Use VLC to stream RTSP feed as HTTP Live Stream

Tags: vlc, rtsp, http-live-streaming

I have a really high quality RTSP feed coming into a windows server.  I'm attempting to use VLC to restream it as Http Live Streaming.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to establish this stream through VLC's graphic user interface as opposed to the command line?  If so, how?

The examples I've found so far (on here and elsewhere) have all been command line examples and none of them have worked at all.

I would love to hear from anyone who has actually accomplished a successful restream of RTSP to an http live stream using a windows server.  Incidentally, I already have the website set up to serve the result, but I can't get the stream to write the .ts files regardless of what I've tried.

I'm stumped. Thanks.

Comment: so we're talking HLS here? This might be helpful... http://superuser.com/a/589352/39364 (or possibly ffmpeg, though that one might be harder...)

Comment: @rogerdpack: Yes, HLS. This is for one of my customers, so (due to project constraints), this one requires the use of VLC. In other words, ffmpeg isn't an option (yet).  I'll try the link you mentioned and report back.  I had not seen that one in my previous searching.

Comment: I tried the script in that link, but still no luck. Now, I'm trying to figure out specifically why it fails.

Comment: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Streaming_for_the_iPhone/ may be useful

Comment: Interesting new information.  I've managed to successfully set this up by tweaking the command line examples I've found, but I've run into a snag.  The HTTP Live stream produced by VLC will not play on iOS devices running iOS 7.  Any guesses why that might be?

Comment: nope.  possibly codec settings (sometimes it only accepts h264 baseline profile?) Feel free to post your working answer as an answer here in the meantime though :)

Answer (score 3):

just look this command for example:

```
vlc -I dummy rtsp://ip:port/blablabla--sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,fps=20,vb=512,scale=1,acodec=none,venc=x264{aud,profile=high,level=60,keyint=15,bframes=0,ref=1,nocabac}}:duplicate{dst=std{access=livehttp{seglen=10,delsegs=true,numsegs=10,index=/var/www/live/mystream.m3u8,index-url=http://ip/live/mystream-########.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=/var/www/live/mystream-########.ts},dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8082/video.mp4}}'
```

Comment: I will comment tomorrow if this works into a web page, meaning the RTSP stream gets converted to a stream which is able to be embedded into a video player in the web browser

Comment: Docs or explanation?

Comment: this is for mp4, but  it not easy to proxy