# Class to read ID3v2 tags of HLS video stream

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, id3v2

I’m developing a sort of Media Player for Windows 10.

This player consists in two tracks: one for video and the other for audio. These two streams come as HLS tracks and use H264 and AAC codecs, respectively.

The way I have implemented this application is using the [AdaptiveMediaSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.media.streaming.adaptive.adaptivemediasource.aspx) class for holding the HLS tracks and the [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx) class for printing their content. Both objects have ID3v2-shaped timed-text metadata, which are embedded in the HLS live stream and I must retrieve them somehow.

Looking for a way to get them, I found the [TimelineMarker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.timelinemarker) class, which is supposed to recieve metadata from MediaElement, but the fact is that when the event is thrown ([MediaElement.MarkerReached](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.markerreached.aspx)) I’m not retrieving anything.

So, I need a kind of listener that notifies me when the tags embedded are decoded or when the playback point reaches the time associated with the tag.

How could I get those tags?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more information about the stream you're receiving? Can you verify that it definitely has the necessary tags, and that they're sent at the start of the stream?

Comment: Yes, specifically I will receive, mostly, live videos. Now I'm testing with a URL which contains the video I'm using. I just need to get the tag `TXXX`, in principle. And yes, I will receive them from the start of the stream, I will have to implement a listener.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. What kind of stream is it (RTP/RTMP/RTSP/MMS/...)? How is the video encoded (MP4/FLV/...)? If it's publicly available, can you post a link to an example?

Comment: The stream is HLS and the codec is H264 and AAC (I have two tracks: one for audio and the other for video).

Comment: I did some reading up on AAC, metadata and MediaElement.Markers. It certainly *looks* like MediaElement should recognise AAC tags. That implies an issue in your source, or an issue in your code. What I would suggest would be to use FFmpeg to create some test files (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC), use VLC to serve them (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148316/use-vlc-to-stream-rtsp-feed-as-http-live-stream), then try using the MediaElement again. This gives you a verifiable, tweakable testing setup. If you can post the code you have now it could be checked for issues.

Comment: Thanks again!! I'll try and give you feedback :)